# CakePHP XDebug Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, cakephp-3.0, xdebug, netbeans-8

I am trying to setup XDebug for my CakePHP application.  Here is my system info:

1. Using WAMP (Windows 10, Apache 2.4.23, MySQL 5.7.14, PHP 5.6.25)
2. CakePHP v3.4
3. Netbeans v8.2

I then click the Debug Project option, under the Debug Menu.  This will start a new browser window, with this URL: http://localhost/MyCakePHPApp/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

Then the browser will just keep spinning.  In the bottom of the browser, it says "Waiting for localhost..."  It will continue to do this until I hit the NetBeans Continue button, twice.  Then the app will load properly.  It's almost like there is a break point somewhere, even though I cannot see it.  in my breakpoint window, I can see that there are no breakpoints set.  Also, if I add a breakpoint to my code, it also never gets hit.

Comment: Well ... collect xdebug log and see where it breaks -- it may give you some hints.

Comment: @LazyOne I don't see any errors in the log.  I did switch some some settings and it no longer hangs, but it also does not stop at break points, though if I add: xdebug_break(); it will break there

Comment: For your first complaint, do you have "stop at first line" checked? Look in Tools->Options->PHP->Debugging and see if stop at first line is checked.  That would cause you initial stop.